# iOS - How to caputre image : resolution 3840x2160, using GPUImageStillCamera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, camera, gpuimagestillcamera

I need to capture highest resolution image using GPUImageStillCamera, I have tried these properties like : AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto, AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080. It gives me little bit fine result. Please note that when I capture image using property AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto instead of AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, then it (AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto) gives better result than AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh. But when I use properties AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160 means :

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack]; .
```

My app crashes (even in latest iPhone version) and shows this message (I am using iPhone 5 S, version:9.3.1, Xcode version: 7.3)

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160
>   is not a supported preset.

Is there a way to check whether is concrete AVCaptureSessionPreset supported on iOS device? I want to set a resolution of AVCaptureSession, but I do not know how to check whether the device is capable to capture camera frames using selected resolution. **In short I need highest quality, largest size image for all different iPhone Devices**. Any suggestion will be great. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVCaptureSession`'s `sessionPreset` property something like below,

```
  cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

You should try `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` in your code also.

Hope this will help :)